# How to send multiple Select2 value to ther server in ajax Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 drop-down in my wep page, I want to send selected value to the servlet using ajax parameter, I tried below Ajax but it's not working for me.

My HTML `Select` Code

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="color" name="color" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Colors">
    <option>Red</option>
    <option>Blue</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Gray</option>
</select>
```

My `Ajax` Code:

```
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'MyServerUrl',                                
         data: {
            color: $("#color").select2('data') 
            },
         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){
         },
         error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         }
     });
```

Is there any way to send Direct object to Ajax Parameter?

Comment: Not sure on the jQuery way of doing this, but `document.getElementById('color'). value` will get the selected value.

Comment: Why didn't you say the issue was reading the POST body in a Java Servlet?

Comment: Yes, Actually I am accessing that parameter value in servlet:
` String[] outerArray = request.getParameterValues("color");`
But not getting in outerArray

Answer (score 1):

`$("#color").val();` will get you an array with selected values. E.g.:

```
["red", "blue", "gray"]
```

But do still have to define values to your options because they have no value now.

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="color" name="color" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Colors">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="gray">Gray</option>
</select>
```

Using the same `val` method you can also set the values programmatically:
`$("#color").val(["blue", "red"]).trigger("change");`

Comment: Hi Nico, I tried `$("#color").val()` but it is giving me comma separated string which I am not able to pass in ajax parameter.

Comment: If you print it, it will LOOK like a comma-separated string, yes. But IT IS in fact an array so it's perfectly possible to pass `color: $("#color").val()` in the body of your POST request. Just try it. In the backend, presumably Java, parse it like `List<String>`.

Answer (score 1):

just use val() and add brackets behind the post variable name

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'MyServerUrl',
      data: {
          'color[]': $('select.select2').val()
      },
      success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR){

      },
      error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      }
 });
```

it should do the magick :)

Comment: @Marko, I tried but, Not working.
On Servlet when I am try to get the `color` parameter value using:
`request.getParameterValues("color")`  also I tried 
`request.getParameter("service_type")` But I am not getting any value :(